# How to resolve "The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference." error?

Tags: c#, manifest, .net-assembly, pdfium

I downloaded source code for pdfiumviewer from git hub. I made changes to one of the projects in that solution.Then I added that project to my application and added reference of that project to one my application's project.I had to uncheck the Signing option for the PDfiumViewer project, as some of the dll in that project are unsigned.I am able to build the application successfully.But at run time when I create an object of one of the class of PDfiumviewer project.It gives me the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'PdfiumViewer, Version=2.11.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

The version number of the assembly is correct.So, why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was that I had added reference of old unmodifed PdfiumViewer dll to another project.Hence, there was conflict between the two dlls (old and customized) at runtime.I removed the old dll reference and it worked.

Comment: yes, thanks for the answer! this error made me waste hours

Answer (score 0):

Ive also encountered this issue, my scenario was thou that I had to add a reference from another solution into my project removing the reference was not an option - what worked for me was reinstall SQLclient from nuget package managerer on both solution. Hopes it helo someone else

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you have a library that references v2.11.0.0 of the Pdfium library. This library could be an assembly that you built earlier, or another assembly that came from Pdfium that references this version of the library. When you built your version of the library you probably didn't use this same version number, and it wouldn't have been strong named correctly. To fix this, you can add an assembly binding redirect in your applications configuration file to redirect the offending library to your custom built one.

I wrote a program to fix this issue automatically: https://github.com/BackTrak/DependencyFixup/releases/tag/1.0.0.0

I know this question is old, but hopefully this helps out others!